# IF statement error in tcsh

Tags: bash, if-statement, tcsh

Having trouble executing an IF statement through tcsh.
This works FINE for me -

```
#!/bin/bash
if echo `cal|tail -6|sed -e 's/^.\{3\}//' -e 's/.\{3\}$//' |tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' | head -11|tail -10|tr -s '\n' ' '`|grep -w `date "+%e"`
then
        echo "present"
else
        echo "absent"
fi
```

This is the PROBLEM -

```
#!/bin/tcsh
if echo `cal|tail -6|sed -e 's/^.\{3\}//' -e 's/.\{3\}$//' |tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' | head -11|tail -10|tr -s '\n' ' '`|grep -w `date "+%e"`
then
        echo "present"
else
        echo "absent"
endif
```

Getting this error-

```
if: Expression Syntax.
then: Command not found.
```

I really need this to run using "tcsh"

Comment: Make sure your script actually ends in `.csh` extension, and not `.sh`. This was a problem for me

Answer (score 2):

First, you've got to know that you can find two different shell families as :

- Bourne type shells (Bash, zsh...)
- C-syntax type shell (tcsh, csh...)

As you can see, Bash and tcsh aren't from the same shell family.
On tcsh, the if statement is a bit different from the bash one because of this.
In your case, the keyword "then" is misplaced.
Try to put it at the end of the "if" line as :

```
#!/bin/tcsh
if(echo `cal|tail -6|sed -e 's/^.\{3\}//' -e 's/.\{3\}$//' \
|tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' | head -11|tail -10|tr -s '\n' ' '`| \
grep -w `date "+%e"`) then
     echo "present"
else
     echo "absent"
endif
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nope, I get the same error again "if: Expression Syntax.". I guess it has something to do with quotes.

Answer (score 2):

That works in `bash` because `if` statements in POSIX-style shells always work by executing a command (and it just so happens that `[` is an alias to the `test` command).

However, `if` statements in `tcsh` don't work like that.  They have their own syntax (described under Expressions in the [`tcsh` man page](http://man.cx/tcsh%281%29)).

Try running the pipeline on its own and then checking the exit status in the `if`:

```
cal | tail -6 | sed -e 's/^.\{3\}//' -e 's/.\{3\}$//' | tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' | head -11 | tail -10 | tr -s '\n' ' ' | grep -w `date "+%e"` >/dev/null
if ( $? == 0 ) then
    echo "present"
else
    echo "absent"
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I will typically do something like this, keeping the conditional statement simple. However, you could cram the variable in the “if” and just check that your grep isn’t empty.

```
set present = `tail -6 .... | grep “”`

if ( $present != “” ) then
   echo “present”
else
   echo “not present”
endif
```

You can also use the “-x” to help debug  #!/bin/tcsh -x. Something this small, an echo to check your variable should do it, but “-x” might give you all the info you need.